# Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift

I new in swift and now learning this hard as i can. I wrote function that got arguments: numbers and function that work with this numbers:

```
func anotherSum(_ numbers : Int...) -> Int {
   return numbers.reduce(0, +)
}

func makeSomething(_ numbers : Int..., f : (Int...) -> Int) {
   print(workFunction(numbers))
}

makeSomething(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, f: anotherSum)
```

But compile gives out error `cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'`
. When i tried to change argument like

`workFunction : ([Int]) -> Int)` and

`func anotherSum(_ numbers : [Int]) -> Int`

It work perfectly, but i still can't understand why realisation with `Int...` doesn't work and why compiler gives this error.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, `Int...` and `[Int]` are completely unrelated types in this context. You need to modify `anotherSum` to take a `[Int]` instead, if you want this to work. There's no current way to "splat" arrays in Swift.

Comment: `Int...` will turn into `[Int]` immediately in the function body. `anotherSum(Int...)` is supposed to take multiple parameters, while each parameter is an `Int`. Calling `workFunction(numbers)` is essentially `anotherSum([Int])`, you've just passed a single parameter, which is `[Int]` not `Int`, to `anotherSum`. That's why types do not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `Int...` is considered as an `[Int]` in the function body so compiler will not allow to pass `[Int]` in place of `Int...`. You better calculate the sum as below,

```
func makeSomething(_ numbers : Int..., workFunction : (Int...) -> Int) {
    let sum = numbers.map({ workFunction($0)}).reduce(0, +)
    print(sum)
}
```

Or introduce another method that accepts array of `Int` and returns sum. Something as below,

```
func anotherSum(_ numbers : [Int]) -> Int {
    return numbers.reduce(0, +)
}

func makeSomething(_ numbers : Int..., workFunction : ([Int]) -> Int) {
    print(workFunction(numbers))
}
```